# How to use ArgumentCaptor in mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm learning Mockito and Unit Testing in general. I want to learn how to unit test better by using Argument Captor. I'm using jdbc to handle my SQL statement. I have a method that inserts a user into my DB.

```
public void insert(User user) {
   String sql = "INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES ?";
   jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
     @Override
     public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) {
       final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.setString(1, user.getId().trim());
       return ps;
     }
   });
 }
```

Below is the test that I'm trying to write with ArgumentCaptor.

```
    @Test
      public void testInsert() {
        User user = new User("testID");
        ArgumentCaptor<PreparedStatementCreator> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(PreparedStatementCreator.class);
        insert(user);
        verify(mockJdbc, times(1)).update(captor.capture());
        PreparedStatementCreator actual = captor.getValue();
        assertEquals(??, actual.createPreparedStatement(??));
      }
```

Any advice or insight on what should be in the '??' for the assert statement or if this is the correct way to use Argument Captor?

Thank You

Edit:

```
      @Test
      public void testInsert() throws SQLException {
            ArgumentCaptor<PreparedStatementCreator> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(PreparedStatementCreator.class);
            PreparedStatement ps = mockConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES ?";);
            ps.setString(1, user.getId().trim());
            insert(user);
            verify(mockJdbcTemplate, times(1)).update(captor.capture());
            PreparedStatementCreator actual = captor.getValue();
            assertEquals(ps, actual.createPreparedStatement(mockConnection));
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your approach of using `ArgumentCaptor`s.

You are using the `ArgumentCaptor` correctly to capture the argument of the method `update` on the mocked JDBC template; however, you cannot extract the argument used to call the `PreparedStatementCreator`, because this is object is not a mock.

Conceptually, the difficulty you have to test this part of your code comes from the fact you don't control the *creation* of the `PreparedStatementCreator`. One possible solution would be to take back control on how and when you create these objects; so as to allow you to mock them in your tests.

Following a standard [creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern), you could introduce a factory which (single) responsibility is to create `PreparedStatementCreator`.

```
interface PreparedStatementCreatorFactory {

  PreparedStatementCreator newPreparedStatementCreator(Connection connection, String sql, User user);

}

public final class DefaultPreparedStatementCreatorFactory {
  @Override
  public PreparedStatementCreator newPreparedStatementCreator(Connection connection, String sql, User user) {
    final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, user.getId().trim());
    return ps;
  }
}
```

Then, in the class you are testing (which contains the JDBC mock), you can *inject* a mock of the `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory`. Then, instead of capturing the argument of the JDBC mock, you can capture the argument on the factory instead; and, of course, specify what the mocked factory returns.

```
PreparedStatementCreatorFactory factory = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.class);
PreparedStatementCreator creator = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatementCreator.class);
// Mock the creator at your convenience.

when(factory.newPreparedStatementCreator(any(Connection.class), any(String.class), any(User.class)).thenReturn(creator);

...

User user = new User("testID");
ArgumentCaptor<Connection> connectionCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Connector.class);
ArgumentCaptor<String> sqlCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
ArgumentCaptor<User> userCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(User.class);

insert(user);

verify(factory, times(1)).newPreparedStatementCreator(connectionCaptor.capture(), sqlCaptor.capture(), userCaptor.capture());

assertEquals(user, userCaptor.getValue());
```

One drawback of this approach is that it adds one level of indirection and *relative* complexity; the main advantage is, as we see, to improve the separation of concerns in your design and *in fine* the testability of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the input, the main reason I want to use ArgumentCaptor is to use ensure that the PreparedStatement is being called with the correct value i.e user.getId(). Would your approach still be used for this?

Comment: @Rp5595 Yes you Should be able to verify the value of the user with the `userCaptor`

Comment: I added an edit to my original post. Could it be possible to just capture the PreparedStatement from the call and compare that to the PreparedStatement that I create locally?

Comment: @Rp5595: No unfortunately, this won't work because `PreparedStatementCreator actual` is not a mock, even though it was captured by the argument captor. This is because the code you are testing *creates* this object, which prevents you to mock it, which is why I introduced this additional factory in my design. It adds arguably some complexity, but this provides you a smaller *single-responsibility* class responsible for the creation of `PreparedStatementCreator`. If you want to share the actual class you are testing, I can add the code I have in mind about how to inject the factory in it.

Comment: Do you have an email in which I can communicate with you over?